# Rewrite main url internally using htaccess file and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I did search for this but so far did not find an answer.

I have a PHP script that is licensed to my main domain: `main.com`
I have an addon domain referring to the `main.com`, but not redirecting: `addon.com`

When I load `main.com`, it works perfectly, but when I load `addon.com`, it refuses to work (Because it is not licensed to addon.com).

I want to internally rewrite the URL using htaccess to change addon.com to main.com.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of "script" are you talking about here - something that runs on the client side, or on the server ...?

Comment: @CBroe It runs on the server side.

Comment: @cbroe put it simply, I need to rewrite the main URL internally.

Comment: I don't think that is actually possible. An internal rewrite requires that the host name of the substitution URL stays the same, otherwise it will automatically become an external redirect. You might have more luck with trying to overwrite environment variables directly from within your script, such as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. You'd kinda have to know what exactly the script evaluates to determine this though. (Maybe asking the provider of your script first, whether an alias domain could be added to your existing license somehow, makes more sense?)

Comment: @cbroe thank you for the reply. unfortunately the script is decoded using ioncube and it is not editable and the provider went out of business two years ago!